# UINavigationBar navigationItem title height

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am using custom font and uppercased text for navigation item title text which contain diacritics. Problem is, the diacritics is cut from top, probably because the title label has wrong height.

So question is, can I affect the title label height? Or access directly the title label and do something like sizeToFit, or change frame or something.

```
// custom font settings
NSDictionary *attr = @{
                       NSFontAttributeName:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"FishmongerK-XCondLight" size:23.0],
                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                       };

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: attr];

// then setting of title
self.navigationItem.title = [NSLocalizedString(@"Oblíbené", nil) uppercaseString];
```

If i try smaller font size, diacritics is still cut from top.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)setCustomNavTitle:(NSString*)title andDescription:(NSString*)desc {

NSString * locname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", title];
NSString * cityname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", desc];
NSString * text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [locname capitalizedString], cityname];

NSDictionary *attribs = @{
                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"222222"],
                          NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:[[Variables getInstance] HelveticaNeue] size:14]
                          };
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attribs];

NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:cityname];
[attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"222222"],
                                NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:[[Variables getInstance] HelveticaNeueLight] size:14]} range:range];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[[Variables getInstance] HelveticaNeueMedium] size:15];
titleLabel.attributedText = attributedText;
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.numberOfLines=0;
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

}